# Convert list to nested dictionary

Tags: python

How do I convert the following into a nested dictionary in Python?

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [{'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc1'},
        {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc2'}, 
        {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc3'}, 
        {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc4'}, 
        {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc5'}, 
        {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Agriculture', 'Account': 'acc1'}]
output = defaultdict(dict)
for person in data:
   output[person['Country']][person['Department']]= [person['Account']]
print(output)
```

Present output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'India': {'Teaching': ['acc5'], 'Agriculture': ['acc1']}})
```

Expected output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'India': {'Teaching': ['acc1','acc2','acc3','acc4','acc5'], 'Agriculture': ['acc1']}})
```

Comment: You're replacing the list each time. You should be adding to it instead. [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) _again_ would help.

Answer (score 0):

your `output` object should be a nestest defaultdict  and instead of assigning the `person['Account']`, you should use `append`

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = [{'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc1'},
...         {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc2'}, 
...         {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc3'}, 
...         {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc4'}, 
...         {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc5'}, 
...         {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Agriculture', 'Account': 'acc1'}]
>>> output = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))
>>> 
>>> for person in data:
...     output[person['Country']][person['Department']].append(person['Account'])
... 
>>> 
>>> output
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10d8b9550>, {'India': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Teaching': ['acc1', 'acc2', 'acc3', 'acc4', 'acc5'], 'Agriculture': ['acc1']})})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [{'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc1'},
    {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc2'}, 
    {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc3'}, 
    {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc4'}, 
    {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Teaching', 'Account': 'acc5'}, 
    {'Country': 'India', 'Department': 'Agriculture', 'Account': 'acc1'}]

output = defaultdict(dict)
for person in data:
   output[person['Country']].setdefault(person['Department'], 
[]).append(person['Account'])

print(output)
```

This is the correct code. All you need to do is you need to change the value of your Department key to Account value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without a `defaultdict`:

```py
output = {}
for person in data:
    ctry, dept, acct = person.values()
    output.setdefault(ctry, {}).setdefault(dept, []).append(acct)
```